# How to optimize code with a lot of constants?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, optimization

There is a code for some mathematical calculations in which not only values are calculated, but also their belonging to an acceptable range is checked. Constants in classes are used to store the range, but this leads to a large number of them, is it possible to optimize this somehow?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum


class RecommendedNumberInputHoles(Enum):
    MAX_NUMBER_INPUT_HOLES = 6
    MIN_NUMBER_INPUT_HOLES = 2


class RecommendedDiameterRange(Enum):
    MAX_RECOMMENDED_DIAMETER = 2.5
    MIN_RECOMMENDED_DIAMETER = 0.5


class RelativeLength(Enum):
    MAX_RELATIVE_LENGTH = 6.0
    MIN_RELATIVE_LENGTH = 1.5


@dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class CentrifugalLiquidInjector:
    outer_diameter_injector: float
    side_wall_thickness_injector: float
    number_input_tangential_holes: float

    diameter_input_tangential_holes: float
    length_input_tangential_holes: float

    relative_length_twisting_chamber: float

    def __post_init__(self):
        if not (RecommendedNumberInputHoles.MIN_NUMBER_INPUT_HOLES.value >= self.number_input_tangential_holes <=
                RecommendedDiameterRange.MAX_RECOMMENDED_DIAMETER.value):
            raise ValueError(f"Значение {self.number_input_tangential_holes} количества входных тангенциальных"
                             f"отверстий не входит в рекомендуемый диапазон"
                             f"[{RecommendedNumberInputHoles.MIN_NUMBER_INPUT_HOLES.value}..."
                             f"{RecommendedDiameterRange.MAX_RECOMMENDED_DIAMETER.value}]")

        if not (RecommendedDiameterRange.MIN_RECOMMENDED_DIAMETER.value >= self.diameter_input_tangential_holes <=
                RecommendedDiameterRange.MAX_RECOMMENDED_DIAMETER.value):
            raise ValueError(f"Значение {self.diameter_input_tangential_holes} диаметров входных тангенциальных"
                             f"отверстий не входит в рекомендуемый диапазон"
                             f"[{RecommendedDiameterRange.MIN_RECOMMENDED_DIAMETER.value}..."
                             f"{RecommendedDiameterRange.MAX_RECOMMENDED_DIAMETER.value}]")

    @property
    def diameter_twisting_chamber_injector(self) -> float:
        return self.outer_diameter_injector - 2 * self.side_wall_thickness_injector

    @property
    def relative_length_tangential_hole(self) -> float:
        value_relative_length = self.length_input_tangential_holes / self.diameter_input_tangential_holes

        if not(RelativeLength.MIN_RELATIVE_LENGTH.value >= value_relative_length <=
               RelativeLength.MAX_RELATIVE_LENGTH.value):
            raise ValueError(f"Значение {value_relative_length} относительной длины входного тангенциального отверстия"
                             f"не входит в допустимый диапазон [{RelativeLength.MIN_RELATIVE_LENGTH.value}..."
                             f"{RelativeLength.MAX_RELATIVE_LENGTH.value}]")
        else:
            return value_relative_length
```

Comment: The default implementation of Python is CPython which is an *interpreter*. Mathematical operations are very (very) slow. While you can pre-compute some constant expression, basic operations are generally 2 order of magnitude slower than compiled code (if not even 3). If you care about speed, then you should use Cython (AOT compiler compatible with CPython) or PyPy (JIT), or possibly not use Python at all...

Comment: What are you wanting to optimize: speed, memory, maintainability, readability, extensibility? I'd give that some thought.

Comment: @nicomp I would improve the readability of the code and its extensibility

Comment: To improve readability and extensibility, make classes around the quantities. For example, everything that you know about an "input hole" should go in the InputHole class. You enforce your constraints, instantiate objects of type InputHole , serialize, print, format, etc. Then that class can move by itself into other projects and it can be used by developers with less domain knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you must use an `Enum` in this way, you would be better served by `IntEnum` because the enum values are `int`s and you won't need `.value` after everything.
2. For testing if something is "in" a range, the pythonic solution is well, the `in` operator -- so you might want to add a custom range class that can be manipulated in this way (the built-in `range` can only do integers):

```py
class AcceptableRange:
    def __init__(self, min, max):
        self.min = min
        self.max = max

    def __contains__(self, val):
        """Return true if the value is within the acceptable range of values"""
        return self.min <= val <= self.max

    def __repr__(self):
        """Format the range for e.g. pasting into error messages"""
        return f"[{self.min}...{self.max}]"

# then use like so:
RelativeLengthRange = AcceptableRange(1.5, 6.0)

...
         # in property relative_length_tangential_hole()
         if value_relative_length not in RelativeLengthRange:
            raise ValueError(f"Значение {value_relative_length} относительной длины входного тангенциального отверстия " # (nitpick: add space)
                             f"не входит в допустимый диапазон {RelativeLengthRange!r}")
         # rest of function
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Enums are not necessary, you could put all the constants in a MappingProxyType.

```
from types import MappingProxyType
const: MappingProxyType = MappingProxyType({"MAX_NUM_IN_HOLES" = 6, "MIN_NUM_IN_HOLES" = 2, "MAX_REC_DIAMETER" = 2.5, "MIN_REC_DIAMETER" = 0.5, "MAX_REL_LENGTH" = 6.0, "MIN_REL_LENGTH" = 1.5})
```

According to the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html): [A MappingProxyType is a] "Read-only proxy of a mapping. It provides a dynamic view on the mapping’s entries, which means that when the mapping changes, the view reflects these changes."

It works like a simple python dict, so you can access its elements by subscription. And if you don't keep a reference to the original dict, it's inmutable.